# Injection & surjection

Tags: functions

Can you give an example of a function from N to N which is neither injective nor surjective? The domain and range are a set of Natural numbers

Comment: Let $f$ map all $N$ to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(n)\mapsto 1$.

$f$ does not reach all values in $\mathbb N$, hence it is not surjective. But it maps to $1$ more than once (in this case $f(n) = 1 $ for all $n\in \mathbb N$), hence it is not injective.